# Coding around #error

Tags: vba, reporting-services

Hi I have 2 cells with dates in them (Say Cell A and Cell B).  I would like to see if Cell A < Cell B.  However, Cell A can be blank sometimes.  In which I would like to just ignore the calculation.

It seems that SSRS evaluates everything, even if it is not in the logical steps for the function because any safe guards I code are ignored.  Thus, I always get an #error when Cell A is blank.

I tried to write some VB code to do this calculation because I thought that would mitigate the problem.  However, the same issue occurs with the following function:

```
Public Function CheckForError(ByVal Baseline as String, ByVal Current As String) As Boolean

If IsError(DateValue(Baseline)) Then
    Return False
Else 
    Return True
    End If
End Function
```

My expression is this:

```
=Code.CheckForSlip(ReportItems("Milestone_Baseline_Date").Value, ReportItems("Milestone_Current_Date").Value)
```

I am obviously expecting the function to return false instead of #error, but this effort does not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was experimenting before I posted the code.  With boolean the same error occurs

Comment: So if I understand your usage, you are calling this function from an Excel field, checking to see if "BaseLine" is a valid date and if it isn't returning false to tell your calling forming not to process this line? (afraid, i'm not to familiar with SSRS, so I might be missing an important piece to understanding your usage)

Comment: @rsoni Post the expression you are using that gives the #error

Comment: If this is in your .rdl, and you are calling this code from the report, I suspect that Baseline is coming through as null. Test for a null/empty value of Baseline first. Also, how about using the IsDate function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Jamie I will try that now,  @psubee2003 this is SSRS 2008

Comment: I still get the error when I use isDate.  It appears that the evaluation of ReportItems("Milestone_Baseline_Date").Value itself is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the String Length does not return null

```
Public Function CheckForError(ByVal Baseline as String, ByVal Current As String) As Boolean


If Len(Baseline) < 1 Then
    Return False
Else 
    Return True
    End If
End Function
```